# Printing out array elements based on elements contents (Java)

Tags: java

I have an array of String like so:

```
array[0] = "1 4"
array[1] = "2 0"
array[2] = "2 1"
array[3] = "4 2"
```

and would like to process the array and print out the second part of the array element
on the same line when the first part of the array element have duplicates, like this:

```
4
0 1
2
```

I've been trying ages to work this out but I keep getting more confused...

Processing is based on consecutive lines.

Comment: FYI that looks like an array, not an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a straight-forward Java coding problem to me:

```
String lastKey = null;
for (String str : array) {
   String[] parts = str.split(" ");
   if (parts[0].equals(lastKey)) {
       System.out.print(" ");
   } else if (lastKey != null) {
       System.out.println();
   }
   System.out.print(parts[1]);
   lastKey = parts[0];
}
System.out.println();
```

This assumes that your input file is ordered on the first field ...

Comment: Yup ... fixed ... (too focussed on the fiddly stuff with spaces and line breaks)

Comment: Ahh yes this is what i needed. Thanks a lot. Makes so much sense now:)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments, it looks like you could use [MultiMaps](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) and simplify the design

```
MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
for ( string line: array) {
   String []pair = line.split(" ");
   mhm.put(pair[0],pair[1]);
}

for (Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.values() ) {
  //print all values from collection?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check index n and n+1 of the array list. Tokenize both the strings and compare the first elements. If the first elements are the same, you can print the second element from both the strings in one line.

I assume that you are not looking for 2 specifically as the first number and you want to check only consecutive elements of the list. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes consecutive elements, not '2' specifically

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the clarification. How big is in the input that you are working on?